# usability issue with nested scroll views on ios

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a horizontal scroll view with paging enabled, and the children of this scroll view are vertical scroll views. It's like the iOS home screen, but imagine scrolling vertically on each home screen.

Now, when the vertical scroll is in progress, it's hard to swipe to the next or previous screen, because the vertical scroll view apparently captures the events. Even if the angle of the swipe is almost horizontal, it doesn't go to the next or previous "page". Only after the scroll stops fully can one easily swipe to the next or previous pages.

Unfortunately, because of the slow deceleration, the user might think the content stopped moving when it is in fact moving very slowly and just about to stop. But the horizontal swipe is interpreted as a vertical scroll gesture, and the scroll velocity increases, making things worse from the user's perspective.

I've noticed multiple people struggling with this when they test out our app, and I wonder if anyone here knows a solution, perhaps a way to consider the angle of the swipe to determine which scroll view should process the event. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest stopping the vertical scroll on a touch begins event. This is how most apps I've seen do something like this.

Comment: Stefan, I don't think so -- you can swipe in a scroll view that's already scrolling, and it continues scrolling, perhaps with a greater velocity, if you flick it in the same direction. That won't work if you stop the scroll on a touch begins event. We need to compute the direction of the swipe and determine if it's horizontal, in which case we stop the vertical scroll. Is there a better way to do this than doing it by hand, and getting many of the edge cases wrong?